# Traffic lights: why yellow before green?

Tags: physical, signs

Traffic lights around the world use the yellow light to warn people that it will soon turn to red, so that people can stop before. This is perfectly understandable.

However, I found out that in some European countries the yellow light is also shown when going from red to green.

Can somebody tell me what's the purpose of this? From my judgement, it is completely unnecessary. It's not like it is warning drivers of any danger. Do drivers need a sign that tells them to "prepare to go, but don't go yet"? And why would they need it?

Comment: Implying that software user interfaces aren't "real world"...? ;)

Comment: It might be the force of habit. A few decades ago, when less-reliable cars were abundant, a few seconds notice was useful to let the driver rev up the engine and shift into first gear without stalling. Sudden-green creates an unwelcome sense of haste if you're driving a jalopy.

Comment: Whatever the reason, I wish we had this in USA. I am tired of looking at the side to look for when the crosstraffic light has turned yellow. Do I need it? No. But if you're impatient it's a nice FYI.

Comment: Off topic - but on the subject of roads: I've always liked the term 'Highway Gothic' for the fonts which are used in the USA: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FHWA_Series_fonts

Comment: I much prefer the light turning immediately green without warning and everybody laying on their horns at the same time depending on who notices first.

Comment: I think it's automatic (us) vs manual (hello europe) transmission.

Comment: In either Taiwan or Thailand, I can't remember where I saw it, they have a countdown timer for both red and green. I wish they implemented that in North America.

Comment: Well, I'm used to the sudden green. You don't need a yellow light to prepare your car to go, you prepare it on green. What's wrong with that? I have my doubts on whether that makes so much of a difference in traffic.

Comment: @djeidot: that means you'll have to be fully concentrating at the light the whole time or you have to be familiar with the light timing on the intersection. If you have yellow (amber) between red->green light, you have time to relax for a while with your hands away from the wheel and your breaks engaged; with sudden green you have to be prepared all the time (lest you be caught surprised by the sudden change).

Comment: Similar discussions: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/11309/traffic-lights-yellow-is-progress-not-state

Comment: Does anyone know of a study that *demonstrates* an advantage to one way or the other?  The *rationales* are interesting but hardly conclusive.

Comment: My car has a turbo diesel engine & it's nice to have those 2 seconds to rev it.  If I didn't then it would be slower to start than a petrol engine.

Comment: In the UK at least, drivers have an annoying tendency to treat yellow as 'go' rather than 'get ready'.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

> Do drivers need a sign that tells them to "prepare to go, but don't go yet"?

That is exactly what this signal is for. It's to stop drivers being surprised when the light turns green and gives the driver time to prepare to move off:

> **Red and Amber**— this combination of bulbs indicates that the lights are about to change to green, and gives drivers time to release their handbrake and prepare to drive off as soon as they are allowed to do so. This phase was first introduced in 1958.

[Source](http://h2g2.com/dna/h2g2/A9559407)

Note the part about releasing the hand brake. Most drivers seem to ignore this, but it is part of the UK driving test that you engage the brake while waiting at lights.

It's also red+amber rather than just amber so that you know which way the light it going to change next should you only see it when it's in the transition state. If you see just amber then you know it's going to turn red imminently so you should be deciding whether it's safe to stop and preparing to stop. If you see red+amber then you know that it's going to turn green so you should slow down and be on the lookout for vehicles that may still be coming through the lights that are turning red.

Comment: Most people take the car out of gear, too.

Comment: Interesting. I've never seen anybody use a hand brake on a light, be it in the U.S. or Europe...

Comment: I've used a handbrake at lights in both Europe and the US.

Comment: You'd find it tricky in a manual to _not_ use the handbrake if you're on a hill facing upwards. Either that, or your clutch won't last long.

Comment: Uhhh I shift my manual into neutral and keep my foot on the brake, why would you use the hand brake thats just silly!  But I would love this in the US as well as it would give me time to get the car into 1st gear without getting startled and racing to get it into gear...

Comment: @emalamisura - Most drivers in the UK don't put the handbrake on all the time either. I certainly don't.

Comment: In the USA it's not a problem going straight from red to green because the vast majority of cars have an automatic gearbox. In Europe, most cars have a manual gearbox, and the green+amber sequence gives you time to get in to first gear.

Comment: I wonder if this wouldn't reduce idling, since you have time to start your car again.  But to be honest, when I hear about 'preparing for green' I'm inclined to think of a drag racing start line, and am glad we don't have this in Canada.

Comment: @Jeremy: Keeping the clutch fully depressed won't wear it.

Comment: @Espen - if you're on a hill and **not** using a handbrake the clutch won't be fully depressed - at least if you want to stay still it won't.

Comment: @ChrisF: But why use the handbrake when you have a foot brake? If I stop at a light I usually keep the foot brake in and the clutch fully depressed.

Comment: @Espen - you have to take your foot off the brake to use the accelerator. Unless you are *very* quick you'll slip back if you try to swap from brake to gas. So you use the handbrake then bring the clutch up to the biting point while "stepping on gas". This holds the car instead of the handbrake.

Comment: @ChrisF: Is it only in Norway we practice hill start before getting our license? Using a handbrake for hill start is for people really bad at hill start and/or to afraid to do hill start - unless you live in San Francisco. That said, my car have hill hold, so I don't have to worry about neither. It also have start-stop, so back on topic - the yellow light gives me time to depress the clutch to start the engine ready for the green light...

Comment: @Espen - We practice hill starts in the UK. And when I learnt we were taught use the handbrake until we'd hit the balance point. Things might have changed in the 30+ years since then, but I doubt it.

Comment: @ChrisF: :-) I can't say if they have changed in 30+ years, but they haven't changed in my 10+ years. Safe driving!

Comment: @Espen No, no, hill start is practice as part of normal driving instruction in France, too… but with the handbrake as it is considered to be the proper method. The other one is for bad drivers who don't know better ;-)

Comment: @Espen: In Germany, using the handbrake is taught as the only way to start when facing uphill. What is a "hill start"?

Comment: Funnily enough, I've been taught both ways. In either of them, you need the "get ready" phase. You need it on bikes as well etc. I so hate it that here in France you don't have that.

Comment: Note that in some countries like austria, traffic lights also blink green before they are turning amber/yellow. I like this, too, since it effectively longens the yellow phase and even tells you how much time you have left to get through. I have no studies for this, but I think more people will stop at amber with this.

Comment: Some UK traffic lights have such a long cycle that as long as I'm not the front car at the lights I both put the handbrake on and kill the engine (thereby reducing localised pollution and saving fuel).

Answer (score 26):

in some countries you are encouraged to turn off the engine on red (to reduce pollution), so the yellow before green tells you that you can turn it on again and prepare to go.

Comment: That would cause a lot of additional wear and tear on the vehicle's starter! Personally, I would be very annoyed if my vehicle or the one in front of me failed to start again because it had been restarted 10+ times per trip.

Comment: @jimp I would be annoyed if my car's quality couldn't cope with the additional starts and stops. In fact, most modern (European) cars feature a [Start-stop system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Start-stop_system)

Comment: As long as you are wating for more than about 15 seconds, most modern cars save petrol by turning the engine off. The starter should cope just fine. Older cars - not so much, maybe :-)

Comment: I would find such an indication helpful. My car shuts the engine off at stops automatically, and having a bit of advance warning before the light turned green would permit me to restart the engine (by easing off the brake) a bit sooner, making for a much smoother start.

Comment: @David: Is this a mechanical problem or an intentional feature? If it's the latter, is this something that has been around or only in certain new cars?

Comment: It's an intentional feature. My car is a Honda Civic Hybrid. (You can disable it.) It's been around since 2003 or so.

Comment: Thanks for the info on the start-stop systems. My vehicles do not have that feature, so I was imagining the government advocating for a manual stop/start at every traffic light.

Comment: @jimp Historically, it was really the government advocating a manual start/stop. With a start/stop feature, you don't really need a warning, you just release the brakes and the motor starts.

Comment: Lots of modern cars have stop start.  The electrical circuit is updated to cope with it.

Answer (score 12):

As far as I recall, (I need to check in "the real world") here in Denmark at least, it's like this:

- From Green towards Red: Yellow alone.
- From Red towards Green: Red + Yellow at the same time

This way the two "modes" can be differentiated while maintaining the "change warning" behaviour.

Comment: yes that's the correct behaviour and it works like this here in Slovenia too. But it doesn't work like this in Italy. In Italy it goes straight from Red to Green and since I just returned from there I can tell you it's quite annoying. It's easier for the eye to register both Red and Yellow turned on, than to register the movement from Red straight to Green. You lose the feeling of how long the Green was already on and it actually happened to me that drivers behind me were beeping. The effect being, I kept my eyes focused on the lights from there on and I don't think that's a good practice.

Comment: How is that *the* “correct” behavior? FYI, it does *not* work that way for most of the european population. In fact, there are many variants in traffic light sequence: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_variations_in_traffic_light_signalling_and_operation

Comment: Since it is a better way it is the *correct* behavior.  Basically saying, "it's great, everyone else catch up already". I think timers would be even better though.

Comment: It does distinguish between "about to be red" and "about to be green". Which is important if you are approaching them.

Comment: Even if it was somehow better, breaking expectations is hardly the “correct” behavior. From a UX perspective, consistency is certainly a lot more important than the slight advantages any particular variant might have.

Answer (score 9):

Efficiency could play a factor.

For example:  Assume two cars are stopped at different red lights.  The first light goes directly from red to green.  The other light goes from red to yellow to green.  Also, the driver in front of the second light knows from experience how long the yellow light will last.  Finally, both lights will turn green at exactly the same time.

Now, ask yourself the following questions:

1. On average, which car will go first?
2. By how much?
3. How many times do people stop at red lights per day in the world?
4. What is the world travel-time difference if the world used one method vs. the other?

Now, being American, I see only red-green lights on a daily basis, and so I am used to them.  Thus, I treat the cross-street's light turning red as my "yellow before green" cue, and know that it'll take about 3 seconds before I get the green.  However, that makes my neck a bit sore, so maybe it is a chiropractor-conspiracy for why countries like mine do not do this.  However, lousy jokes aside I'd opt for red-yellow-green scheme if I had the choice.

Comment: +1 - wanted to say the same thing: you get a little bit more cars over during the green phase, which may be good when traffic volume is high.

Comment: Incidentally, in Europe, most of the time, you can't see the cross-street's lights.

Answer (score 6):

To play devils advocate, the Red-Yellow > Green pattern of lights can be more dangerous than a plain Red > Green. With the Red > Green pattern, When you are approaching a red light, unless you know the intersection very well, you must make the assumption you are going to come to a full stop.

With the Red-Yellow > Green pattern, you are given warning that the light is about to turn green, which in turn means that you can anticipate the green light and not brake as hard, or perhaps even realise you have time to speed up or not brake at all, which means you would reach the intersection sooner than you otherwise would.

This is a problem if someone at the crossroad is impatient and runs the red light at the very last second. If a Red>Green scenario, the driver approaching the intersection will typically have a much lower speed, meaning that the impact of any accident is severely deceased, perhaps even avoided. If the approaching driver anticipated the green light, the impact would be much worse for both parties.

<sub>As an anecdote, there was a Red-Yellow > Green set of lights near where I used to live in Melbourne, Australia. It was the last one left in the city and was left-over from the 1960's. They operated perfectly, but for some reason the council changed it to a Red > Green cycle in the early 2000's. Don't know why. And for the record, I do what everyone else seems to anyway which is watch the lights on the road to see when they go yellow, and would love the Red-Yellow > Green pattern myself.</sub>

Comment: Traffic lights (in Germany, anyway) have an phase were all lights are red, as to reduce this security risk. The duration of this phase depends on the size of the intersection, because it's at least "the time time to leave the intersection when entering it at the moment the light turned red". So the additional Red-Yellow gives some security margin, actually.

Comment: Your comment covers such a very specific case that most people won't find themselves in. Having red+green means you better can anticipate when it turns green as you approach, so you can drive more environmentally friendly. I feel like there are many more benefits of the extra step than without it.

Answer (score 5):

Here in the UK we have a nice 'relaxed' (ie quite long)  yellow phase between Red and Green:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zn-woMkK9is&NR=1&feature=endscreen

It's a bit like 'Ready, STEADY, Go' - rather than 'Ready - Go'.  It gives you a bit more time to get ready to go without feeling stressed about it.

I've found driving in countries where it goes straight from red to green a bit more stressful.

I suspect it reflects 'cultural characteristics (conformity / impatientness / etc)' of the country.

Comment: it's more like 'Halt, Go' vs 'Halt, Ready, Go'

Answer (score 3):

At holiday in Asia I've seen a countdown indicating how long the actual light keeps till next change.

So you see how long it will be green and how long it will be red. I really love that idea. In Germany most people would act like Vettel, though.

[image]

Source: http://tripwow.tripadvisor.com/slideshow-photo/count-down-timer-on-traffic-lights-by-travelpod-member-flash101-bangkok-thailand.html?sid=14706062&fid=tp-3

Comment: Also Bulgaria has some counters like this.

Comment: You guys don't have this in most European countries? I thought that's where we got the idea from.

Comment: In Singapore, the local authorities specifically chose not to implement this. The reason is to allow variable length of green-light. For example, if sensors detected an ambulance approaching, the lights will change to minimize the ambulance's waiting time.

Comment: Timers only work for when traffic is heavy enough for the full time to run out. But if there are no cars on the road, it will turn red earlier, and the next road will therefore have to turn green before the timer runs down. Then a road can skip the queue and get green earlier to let emergency vehicles and busses through quicker.

Answer (score 2):

I'm living in germany and we do have the 3 step traffic lights everywhere.
As for the first point, I completely disagree with ALoR's answer. It's simply wrong.

> in some countries you are encouraged to turn off the engine on red (to reduce pollution), so the yellow before green tells you that you can turn it on again and prepare to go.

Turning off the engine won't save petrol at all, not even on large crossroads. As a direct result of this it also doesn't reduce pollution.

You can think of it "when the (us?) traffic light is still red, the *european* already has turned into yellow". From my driving licenses' book:

> Auf die Weiterfahrt vorbereiten

Which means basically

> Prepare to go on driving

The main advantage is: You can start quicker. This may sound a bit silly, but it has a large effect on traffic. Im very curious the 3-state-traffic-light isn't there all around the world.

You can spare time, gas and reduce traffic density.
I think it's a fine addition to the red-green-traffic-light.

Information source: My driving instructor & experience :)

Comment: Actually I noticed this in Germany too :)

Comment: Turning off the engine **does save petrol** on any stop over about 15 seconds, for most modern cars. And thus pollution as well!

Comment: @RoryAlsop Even if that would be a point for turning off the engine, it would be a very inefficient one. Spark plug and many other parts are getting very worn if you turn on and off the motor on every crossroad. I don't really want to know the average $/(saved pollution). You probably search on the wrong place there. Additionally, no serious guy *really* turns off the motor - it's simply too inconvenient and how can't say how long you will actually stop.

Comment: @Michael - no, actually all the major global manufacturers are starting to develop automatic power down/restart systems because of the savings in fuel and wear. This has been around for some time in Europe and Japan, and is now available on Ford SUVs and other vehicles even in the US. Your spark plugs and other parts may suffer on old inefficient engines, but not on new cars. I can't believe you find the couple of seconds an inconvenience - the yellow before green gives you ample time to start the engine.

Answer (score 2):

Wether by design or accidentally, I think the yellow signal has a greater impact on **pedestrians** than drivers.

In cities where lights go straight from red to green the crosswalks are full of stragglers when the signal changes.  When there's a yellow signal in between drivers are already revving their engines and green really means go.  From my personal, wholly unscientific observations, pedestrians quickly learn to respect and follow the crosswalk signals when they see that drivers have the yellow transition light.

Comment: I don't follow that. Pedestrians have flashing green lights warning that it's going to turn to red, and the red light for pedestrians shows up 3-4 seconds before the green light for cars shows. Plus, in most cases pedestrians can't see the traffic lights for cars.

Comment: Flashing green lights are not available, for example, in Germany (but e.g. in Austria).

Comment: To add to what Mike said, even if pedestrian signals were available everywhere, there would still be people who might not be able to cross the road quickly enough, especially if there are a lot of people crossing the intersection at the same time. These stragglers are often the people most likely to get hit by a car--children, the elderly, disabled, or those with limited mobility. 3-4 seconds might not be enough for them to even react to a signal change, let alone safely cross to the other side.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is simply caused by most European cars using manual transmission, unlike cars in the U.S., which usually have automatic transmission.

When stopping on a light with a manual transmission, you might shift into neutral for the wait. When the light turns yellow, you'd shift into first, and then when it turns green, you'd start going.

With an automatic transmission, you simply hit the brake and then gas, so there's no need for the extra step (shift into first) like in manual transmission cars.

Comment: If the US users would have the yellow light, they could start to press the gas pedal at yellow and release the brake pedal when the red goes off. ;) (Of course this would require the usage of both feet)

Answer (score 2):

A French friend of mine once answered my asking of this question by saying that their light durations tend to be quite long, so the norm is to switch your car's engine off while you wait. The amber warning is then used as an indication to start your engine again and prepare to disembark.

Here in South Africa our standard light durations are relatively short, in the 15 to 30 second range, so it seems odd to us, but it could make sense if your light duration is 30 seconds and longer.

Answer (score 2):

Modern city traffic lights often have a ["green wave" system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_wave), where you can drive at the legal speed limit and always encounter green. If you are the first car in such a "wave" then the light will turn green just before you cross its line. Without a pre-green phase (in practice red-yellow) this doesn't work; you'd have to reduce speed in case the green wave has ended or been overruled.

Answer (score 1):

## **Baking FRESH ALASKA**

The purpose of the Red-to-Yellow-to-Green system is to increase throughput, due to FRESH ALASKA!

If you don't know what that is, you shouldn't feel bad, as it's because I just reverse engineered it to fit my answer. I will setup and define both acronyms below. I will prove that in a Red-to-Yellow-to-Green system, more cars will be able to go through the light because more drivers will be prepared to go in according unison.

---

First, let's look at the opposite to demonstrate its defect:

**Red-to-Green**

Imagine an infinite number of cars waiting at a red light. We'll label the first car, "Car A", the second car, "Car B", and so on all the way to infinity.

At the instant the light changes from red to green, Car A and Car B have a special relationship that exists for every successive pair:

- For some time X, Car B must wait for Car A to move, since it is not
  sure if Car A knows the light is green.

X is normally a fraction of a second, but it must exist. If it did not exist, then Car B would step on the gas as soon as the light turned green, assuming Car A was immediately aware that the light was green.

Again this carries on for the B-C relationship, the C-D relationship and on into infinity.

Let's call this FRESH, or:

- Fractionally Related Effectual Summation of Hesitation

You can guess that as we move toward infinity, all of these fractions of a second add up and the end result is a particular average number of cars making it through the light.

- Let's call this average the "Red-to-Green Average Throughput".

FRESH, then contributes negatively to the Red-to-Green Average Throughput.

---

Now, let's take a look at the competing model:

**Red-to-Yellow-to-Green**

Reset the infinite number of cars scenario with everything labeled the same way. The special relationship of pairs still exists, as Car B will still not step on the gas until it is sure that Car A is moving.

This time, however, Car B will be more confident that Car A will be moving when the light turns green because of at least three factors:

1. Car A has a high likeliness to know that green is coming because of
   the yellow transition stated.
2. Dependent on the first factor being a success, Car A is more likely
   to be alert and therefore prepared to move (Important if they are
   driving multi taskers).
3. If the driver of Car A is an every day driver at this light, they
   are more likely to know the pre-red yellow duration due to
   familiarity of the yellow light time.

For these reasons, ALASKA can be introduced as:

- Accorded Likeliness Anticipating Surely Known Alertness

For those in the real world Red-to-Green system, how many times have you been in the position of Car B when the light turns green, only to look ahead at Car A and notice they are head down looking at their cell phone or doing their makeup or eating a sandwich? They could be doing any number of things and have no time to prepare to drive. I would be willing to bet that this happens more often in the FRESH driven Red-to-Green system than the ALASKA driven Red-to-Yellow-to-Green system.

---

**Conclusion**

Because of the negative effects of FRESH and the positive effects of ALASKA, I now feel comfortable in saying this:

- Red-to-Yellow-to-Green Average Throughput > Red-to-Green Average
  Throughput

This explains the purpose of the Red-to-Yellow-to-Green system as a means to move more cars through the light for any given time when compared to the Red-to-Green system.

Comment: -0, for lame abbreviations.

Answer (score 1):

Traffic signals sequences often date back at least to the 1960s so it's often difficult to find relevant documentation and to know what the original intent was. Once a particular sequence is established in a country, it tends to stick and for good reasons also (e.g. cost of changing existing traffic lights, training/information need and driving errors created by any potential change, etc.) Even if it is tempting to consider the particular sequence you learned as the “correct” one, the value of consistency and stability should not be underestimated.

Still, there is quite a lot of research on the effect of various signals on traffic, using either models of traffic flow or simulator studies (field studies and especially before-after studies seem somewhat rarer nowadays). The particular sequence you describe is known as “starting-amber” and it has been found to increase crossroad capacity but also to increase the number of people crossing while the light is red.

An overview of this research with some relevant references can be found in this report of the TRL in the UK: http://www.trl.co.uk/online_store/reports_publications/trl_reports/cat_road_user_safety/report_literature_review_of_road_safety_at_traffic_signals_and_signalised_crossings.htm

Answer (score 0):

After talking to my car racing brother, the joint theory is that this order of lights is leftovers from the manual transmission days. The yellow signal gives extra time to regain attention and switch into the first gear from neutral. Unlike automatic transmission, the process is multi-step and can result in a stalled engine if the steps aren't followed.

Comment: When I drive a manual transmission and make a stop, I shift into first so all I have to do to start is release the clutch and hti the gas.  Is that not normal?  It doesn't seem to be any slower than with an automatic, though it's true that less-experienced drivers may stall and that would be a delay.

Comment: You _can_ keep the car in the 1st gear while stopped but you have to keep your foot on the clutch pedal. When the car is in neutral, no action is necessary - some drivers relax their legs at traffic lights.

Comment: Manual tranmission days? LOL Where do you live? My car is still very much manual transmission and I am unlikely to switch to automatic transmission at any time in my life... :)

Comment: I read the same explanation on Wikipedia but I am not entirely convinced. With an automatic transmission, you need either to press the brake (if the road is flat) or switch to N or P (if the road is not flat and you want to relax your leg), so you always need to switch pedals or change gear/mode. Both can be done quickly if you have some experience and both can go wrong if you are not used to it (true you can't stall the engine with an automatic but if you drive for some time in a country where manual transmissions are common, you will notice that this isn't really a common problem).

Comment: @MonicaCellio: you should not press the clutch for the whole red-phases because this will increase the wear of the clutch. It should be enough to hit the clutch and insert the first gear when the crossing pedastrian's traffic lights turn red.

Comment: The other argument to switch to neutral is safety -- if you accidentally release the clutch, your car might make a small jump forward, which could be thought of as a bad idea if pedestrians are crossing at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

In Pakistan, traffic lights generally go red>yellow>green and either green>yellow>red (or, more frequently now) green>red. The idea being a gradual slowing down and speeding up of traffic flow, plus (possibly only in our case) giving stragglers--vehicles and/or pedestrians--time to safely clear the crossing before the signal changes.

Answer (score 0):

This is the right topic for discussion and most US citizens raise the question when they visit Europe. There are lots of answers but one of my friends explained that it might be due to manual and automatic transmission. In Europe, we can see manual transmission on priority but things are different If we're talking about the US. American use automatic transmission vehicle that doesn't take nap at red lights. But, Europeans need to get prepared before starting the car that's why the yellow light indicates to start the car and when it's green you can go. Some of my American friends love the European traffic light policy that can save from mishappening.